# Install older version of composer on docker

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I am trying to run my laravel app on docker. Its an old app I am trying to resurface and was built on php 7.1

Locally, it works fine.

On Docker, I used the following config:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer​ | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install
```

Its not allowing me to install composer and gives the following error:

> [stage-0 7/7] RUN composer install:
> #0 0.221 Composer 2.3.0 dropped support for PHP <7.2.5 and you are running 7.1.33, please upgrade PHP or use Composer 2.2 LTS via "composer self-update --2.2". Aborting.

I tried doing `RUN composer self-update --2.2` instead but its the same error.

Can anyone tell me how to go install this specific version of composer on docker.

Thank you

Comment: Instead of `COPY --from=composer:latest`, copy from an older version?

Comment: **LTS** is the hint of the day in that message, use `COPY --from=composer:lts` for the docker-hub distribution. Or as that is your build, pin the version, that is use a concrete versin so you know the last known good, e.g. try 2.2.18:  `COPY --from=composer:2.2.18` (anything **2.2.x** is the Composer **LTS** version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All composer releases are accessible via their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/composer/composer/releases), including the `composer.phar` binary archive files. Instead of installing the latest version from getcomposer.org, just use a version that works with your PHP version.

The `composer.phar` for composer 2.2.9 can be found here: https://github.com/composer/composer/releases/tag/2.2.9

Answer (score 1):

Composer installer permit to choose the version:

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer​ | php -- \
   --2.2 \
   --install-dir=/usr/local/bin
```

See https://getcomposer.org/download/